# open gl window not showing?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
void display(void) {
    float cx = 200, cy = 200, rad = 50;
    float startx = cx - rad;
    float starty = cy;
    int x = startx, y = starty;

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2f((x - 250.f) / 250.f, (250.f - y) / 250.f);

    while (x < cx + rad) {    
        x++;
        y = cy - sqrt(rad * rad - (x - cx) * (x - cx));
        // y = sqrt(rad*rad - (x-cx)*(x-cx))-cy;
        glVertex2f((x - 250.f) / 250.f, (250.f - y) / 250.f);
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }

    glFlush();    
    glEnd();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    gebtutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("CpViewer");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to implement an algo to drawn a circle but i m not getting any output. i am also not able to see the opengl graphics window it appears transparent . what's wrong with
this code.??

Comment: Use glutSwapBuffers instead of glFlush

Comment: glFlush, glFinish and …SwapBuffers invalid within a glBegin…glEnd block.

Answer (score 5):

You are requesting a double-buffered window with that `GLUT_DOUBLE` flag. But you never swap the buffers. So what happens is that you draw all the time into the back buffer, and the front buffer is just undefined and nothing will ever be shown.

You should add a `glutSwapBuffer()` call when you finished drawing a frame, typically at the very end of your `display()` function. And while you're at it: Remove that `glFlush()` call. You put it inside an `glBegin()/glEnd()` block, where it will not work at all, and you won't need it. Also make sure that the `glutSwapBuffers()` call is added *after* the `glEnd()`.